# How to Make This Model With Only Textures/maps

Tags: modeling, texturing

I want to create something that looks like metal mesh and there are alot of tutorials but I can't make the model with only maps, is it possible?

How do you make an alpha map from the side?

[image: View 1][image: Back view][image: View 3][image: View 2]

Comment: so have you tried to bake the height or the normals to see how it looks like?

Comment: i am totqaly new, what does bake mean?

Comment: it means creating a map that will fake the 3D reliefs, is it not what you're asking for?